# How to sharing Android VPN with Linux?

Tags: linux, android, wifi-hotspot, connection-sharing

I have a rooted galaxy note5 with Android 7, and an Asus laptop with Ubuntu 16.04. I like to share my phone VPN connection with my laptop.
I tried some apps like VPNTether,DF tethering fix, TetherNet, Pdanet+, etc. but they didn't work!

I think I could use the VPNTheter on windows 10 and it worked, but they don't work on Ubuntu!

Also I tested two Wi-Fi and USB cable methods.

Also I found this method but couldn't understand what it says in numbers 6 and 7 ?

```
  1.  You need a rooted device
  2.  Make sure you have a VPN app, like OpenVPN or DroidVPN ( I use DroidVPN and its the best)
  3.  Download Terminal Emulator
  4.  Activate your hotspot and connect to your VPN
  5.  Launch Terminal emulator and on the first line type "su" (without the quotes) and press enter

  6. Copy and paste this to the Terminal Emulator. Make sure to paste to a new folder using Root Browser first and copy to T.E. in the exact format as shown below:

iptables -t filter -F FORWARD
iptables -t nat -F POSTROUTING
iptables -t filter -I FORWARD -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
ip rule add from 192.168.43.0/24 lookup 61
ip route add default dev tun0 scope link table 61
ip route add 192.168.43.0/24 dev wlan0 scope link table 61
ip route add broadcast 255.255.255.255 dev wlan0 scope link table 61

  7. That's about it. Also, be sure to make a folder with Root Browser and paste the code there, as this resets after re-boot. It worked on my LG G3 on android 4.4.2
```

Comment: You replaced `192.168.43.0` with the correct addresses for your device?

Comment: @dirkt : No. where should I find the correct address? Also, where should I save this code file for later usage?

Answer (score 1):

First install Proxoid from Google Play Store. It is a mini proxy server. It does not require root. After installing Proxoid, download ADB (Android Debug Bridge) for linux. Then extract it to a empty folder. Now open Proxoid on your android and start proxy server by ticking the checkbox. Now connect your android with your pc via a USB cable. Now to open a terminal session to the folder where the file named `adb` is saved. Now to execute these commands as a standard user:

```bsh
./adb tcpip 5555
```

Now to unplug USB cable. Now start wifi hotspot on your android. Now connect your PC to the network and execute:

```bsh
./adb connect 192.168.43.1:5555
```

Note when android create a wifi hotspot, the IP address of your phone in that network is usually `192.168.43.1`. But it is possible to be other than it. So if the above command don't work then change `192.168.43.1` with your appropriate IP address inside that network. Now to execute these commands:

```bsh
./adb forward tcp:8080 tcp:8080
```

Now configure your system to use http://localhost:8080 as proxy server. Note, after executing the first command once, you don't need execute it until you restart your PC or android device. And if you want to connect via USB cable, you just need to execute the last command.

Answer (score 0):

the commands work in my phone(Android 9).
you can use app like  root explore or mt brown(app in China and can't find in google play)，

- create a new file like `any-name.sh`,
- copy the code into the file,
- run the file after connection to the vpn.

[image]